# Cell reference to named area, with offset

Tags: reference, offset, openoffice-calc

This is a question about OpenOffice spreadsheet, *not* Excel.

I have a named range which is a row of cells. (Say, the name in B4, the range C4:K4). I want to put a row of formulas underneath, where each formula references the cell within the named range at the same column. (The formula in C5 references C4, in D5 references D4, etc.).

Of course I could just use standard relative referencing, but I'd prefer to use the range naming.

How to do that?

I've played with `COLUMN()`, `INDEX()`, `OFFSET()`. I just get invalid reference errors.

Supplementary: there's something in Excel where you highlight a cell with relative references, and get it to recast the formulas using range-names. That might be called `Names -> Apply` IIRC. Is there something comparable in OpenOffice?

Comment: I'm making some progress using array formulas (is that the only way? the best way?): if the array formula spans columns corresponding to the named range, using the name in the formula seems to mean in each cell take the value from the corresponding cell in the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your formulae are in columns C:K this is very simple, for example B5:B7 show the formulae in C5:C7 that have been copied across to ColumnK:

[image: implied intercept example]

Why this is so is difficult to describe, but for Excel [Doc.AElstein](https://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/1172587-excel-vba-interception-and-implicit-intersection-and-vlookup.html) has attempted an explanation.

Comment: OK, so it's simpler than I remembered. This also works if you have names for the rows as well as the columns, put `=Col*Row` at the intersection. It suffers the dangers of all spreadsheets that you can put inconsistent formulas in the cells of the grid, so I prefer array formulas (using names). Still haven't found in OpenOffice anything to `Apply` names to a formula with relative references.

Comment: BTW that Doc.AElstein article is terrible. There's no need for "I made that title up myself." or "My idea of how Excel works ...". And there's no need to invent a new term 'CS Entry' when there's already 'Array formulas'. (Anyway there's other ways to enter Array formulas than with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.)